# SwiftUI - How to change the color of a custom SF symbol in a Text View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5, ipados

So, I have a Text in a SwiftUI view that has a custom SF symbol in it:

```
Text("This is some text with a   \(Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "customSFSymbol")!))  symbol.")
```

The problem is the following:

I want to make all that view white, but when I add the `.foregroundColor(Color.white)` to the view, the SF Symbol stays in a black color.

You can see how it looks right now [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI8qL.png)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What happens if you use `.withTintColor(_:renderingMode:)`, like this: `.withTintColor(UIColor.white, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)`?

Comment: You can addd `.renderingMode(.template)` to the `Image`

Comment: =>`Text("This is some text with a   \(Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "customSFSymbol")!).renderingMode(.template))  symbol.")`

Comment: Thank you so much @CédricBhr! That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `.renderingMode(.template)` to the `Image`

```
Text("This is some text with a   \(Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "customSFSymbol")!).renderingMode(.template))  symbol.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is some text with a ").foregroundColor(Color.red) + imageText + Text("symbol.").foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var imageText: Text {
        Text("\(Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil"))")
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

[image: blue symbol within red text]